# Error After Duplicating Storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, storyboard

Previously i had an existing iphone project.

Afterwards i want to create its iPad version so I duplicated the existing iPhone MainStoryboard to save my time, so I changed the line:

`targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch"`

from the new storyboard (named MainStoryboard_iPad) to:

`targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch.iPad"`.

Finally I set Main Storyboard in iPad Development info to "MainStoryboard_iPad. But I don''t know why some how i got this error:

> 2012-10-11 13:28:07.852 CollViewSmpl[3170:c07] *** Assertion failure in -[PSUICollectionView _dequeueReusableViewOfKind:withIdentifier:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2372/UICollectionView.m:2249 
>       2012-10-11 13:28:07.878 CollViewSmpl[3170:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier cellID - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

Anyone know what could cause this error and give me some workarounds? FYI, I use open source PSUICollectionView library inside the project in place of UICollectionView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That inconsistence error is because the storyboard source code were not being saved properly. Finally i created a new storyboard document targeted for iPad. I copied all source code of the preexisting iPhone storyboard and pasted them into the new one. I didn't forget to save the document (this is important) and gotcha, all the stuffs are now working very well.